# What API can I use to both send and receive monetary payments programatically?

Tags: web-applications, paypal, stripe-payments, e-commerce, payment-gateway

My idea is to have a peer to peer eCommerce service, that will allow buyers to pay into a central account, wait until they have confirmed their order, and then have the central account pay into a seller account, as a sort of middleman. Ideally, the user accounts will be Venmo or Paypal, considering an already high adoption rate.

I was researching the Mindtree and Stripe API's, but I don't think they support paying into user accounts. Is there some sort of API that allows this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is stripe connect (https://stripe.com/en-no/connect)